# Замена стрелочной функции

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Если убрать стрелочную функцию и написать в формате
    "function(arg) { // Code }"

```
function removeTransition(e) {
    if(e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    this.classList.remove('active');
}

var keys = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
```

какой вид будет у этого?

Comment: Вопрос, зачем? (15...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логично что такой:

```
function removeTransition(e) {
    if(e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    this.classList.remove('active');
}

var keys = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
keys.forEach( function(key) {
    key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition)
});
```